# How to stop upload a second image on dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNxRzd)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
                <span>Upload or drag patient photo here</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
        acceptedFiles:  ".png,.jpg",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        url: "#"
    });

    var fileName = $('#profilePicture').val();
    var mockFile = { name: fileName, size: 12345 };
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eubcS91wUNg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAL0/iE1Hduvbbqc/photo.jpg?sz=104");
```

How do I disable uploading of images if there is already a file?

I want something like:

```
if(image exist){
   disabled upload
}else{
   enabled upload
}
```

How can I do this in my example?
I need a variable to store if there is a file or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxFiles`.

```
maxFiles:1,
init: function() {
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            this.addFile(file);
      });
}
```

**From** [DropZone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-maxFiles)

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RarGdP)**

Comment: is not ok for what you put any way I can add a picture, try to edit Example

Comment: Dude, in your codePen you didn't write "maxFiles" you wrote "maxfiles". Make sure to camelcase it.

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is, we added adoua MAXFILES but can add a picture ... trying to see
If you succeed here, please put link

Comment: @D.Cristi I added codePen link, you just can upload one file, if  you browse more than one file it show an error. check it out.

Comment: Yes, and your example can add as many images you want ... not tested? I want a picture if there was only allows you to add

Comment: remove all your uploaded photos then try again. @D.Cristi

Comment: if(have at least one image)
       {
         alert("You can not add an image that already exists")
       }else{
         alert("You can upload file now")
       }

Comment: I put the code that they write ... I do not want to delete the picture default because only then is ok in my site.
I must have an image added default and if there was only stretch to upload

Comment: You want new image going to replace with default one? @D.Cristi

Comment: you did? you can put the link?